# On Safari on mac OS, permissions API for geolocation gives "prompt", not "denied". How do I know if a permission was previously denied?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I am using On Safari 17.1.2 on mac OS 14.1.2

If I go to Settings > Websites > Location, and the website I'm only shows "Deny", this tells me that, for that website, the system will never even ask a user if the website requests their location using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)`.

On Chrome and FireFox, this means that if I run:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

This shows me:

```
PermissionStatus { name: "geolocation", state: "denied" ... }
```

My web application can then use this information to display something like: "Cannot get your location" instead of "Click here to use your location".

However, if I run the above code on Safari

```
PermissionStatus { name: "geolocation", state: "prompt" ... }
```

Based on this, my website displays a link "Click here to use your location", but when the user clicks it, it uses `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` which automatically fails.

I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug or if I'm using the Permission API wrong. Regardless, is there a way in which Safari can know if, for a given site, the user does not want to share their location?

Comment: I suspect Apple decided that it was a privacy violation to disclose this to the application.